# A more elegant way to sort 3 lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists that I want to sort the lists "relative" to each other (for example, picturing each list as a row in a 3x3 matrix, I want to sort it by columns) .

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this. What I come up with is using a temporary list, below is a simplified example:

```
list1 = ['c','b','a']
list2 = [6,5,4]
list3 = ['some-val-associated-with-c','another_value-b','z_another_third_value-a']


tmp, list2 = (list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda pair: pair[0])))
list1, list3 = (list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list3), key=lambda pair: pair[0])))

print(list1, '\n', list2, '\n', list3)

[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Output (the actual AND desired output):

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] 
 [4, 5, 6] 
 ['z_another_third_value-a', 'another_value-b', 'some-val-associated-with-c']
```

And what I not want is:

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
 [4, 5, 6] 
 ['another_value-b', 'some-val-associated-with-c', 'z_another_third_value-a']
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sort relative to each other"? Would if your original lists were `[6, 2, 1], [5, 4, 3]`?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the elements of list2 and list3 by the elements in the corresponding positions in list1?

Comment: from the example it's difficult to tell how this is different from just using `list1.sort();list2.sort();list3.sort()`.

Comment: sorry, this was a really bad example. I hope the EDIT makes it more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list1, list2, list3 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2, list3)))
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the `key` argument, in case the elements of `list2` and `list3` are expensive to compare or raise an exception when compared. Also, `map(list, ...)` if it's important to have lists at the end.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that solves it perfectly. For some reason I was always 100% the opinion I can only zip() 2 objects, my bad.

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ, you have an extra item in the first list. `zip` trunates to the shortest list. If the lists aren't all the same length, you'll have to specify what should happen in that case